# how do I change time zone of Google ads account ,

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

> Your Google Ads and AdSense account time zones don't match. Using the same time zone in both accounts ensures the best reporting results.

I'm getting this notification in my Google admob account,if this notification is going to affect my account, what should I do